# Excel Retention Calculation

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, retention

Excel Masters,

I have an Excel worksheet with a list of employees (ColumnA), dates (ColumnB), and Customers(ColumnC). I want to calculate the employees retention rate based on the customers that visited.

- If a customer visited an employee and came back the next month and visited the same employee, they are considered retained for that employee.
- If a customer visited an employee and came back the next month and visited a different employee, they are considered retained.
- If a customer visited in one month, but didn’t come back the next month, they are considered lost.

```
    Employee  Date      Customer
    Zach      11/2/19   Tyler
    Zach      11/20/19  Tyler
    Zach      10/2/19   Tiffany
    Zach      10/3/19   Tiffany
    George    11/1/19   Tiffany
    George    11/9/19   Tyler
    George    10/2/19   Mike
    George    10/30/19  Michael
```

I want to see a % retention for each employee across all months that are in the data.

At the moment, I've tried using a combination of COUNTIFS to find the solution but with no luck.

Comment: Care to include some sample data, expected output, your current attempted code/formulas?

Comment: @JvdV, added. apologies for not including.

Comment: Best is to add as markdown, so other people don't have to recreate your data. Also, please include your `COUNTIFS` attempt and your actual expected output (as numbers) next to your data.

Comment: Do we need to look at the month number or the number of days to determine the month difference? That is, if the first visit is 01.10 and the next visit is 30.11, it is considered an retained or lost customer?

Comment: Just the month number, so I did =month(Date) and converted to number and used that for comparison.

Comment: Any chance you can load this into a database and do it there?  A DBMS would handle this task nicely.

Comment: Unfortunately no, this is for a small business and wants to keep things simple. Thank you though @Hambone for the suggestion.

Comment: Are "retained for that employee" and "retained" equivalent, or are these counted separately? Also, where are you reporting the results?

Comment: @rmbradburn they are the same, so if a customer visits a different employee the next month, the employees retention does not go down. Results would be simple table showing employee name and their %retention.

Comment: I dont see any **Employee Retained** example in your data. Can you add an example of that?

Answer (score 1):

I can offer an in-place calculation, but it can also be converted to a separate report.

Formula for 'Retained' calculation:

```
=--(SUMPRODUCT(--(C2=$C$2:$C$11);(--(MONTH(B2)+1=MONTH($B$2:$B$11)))+(--(MONTH(B2)-1=MONTH($B$2:$B$11))))>0)
```

Array formula for 'Retention %' calculation (for employee across all clients):

```
{=SUM(IF(A2=$A$2:$A$11; IFERROR(1/(COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$11; A2; $C$2:$C$11; $C$2:$C$11;$D$2:$D$11;1));0); 0))/SUMPRODUCT(1/COUNTIF($C$2:$C$11;$C$2:$C$11))}
```

[image]

**Edit:**

Just add example with an percentage report in a separate table. Same formula, just moved to new area:

```
{=SUM(IF(G2=$A$2:$A$11; IFERROR(1/(COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$11; G2; $C$2:$C$11; $C$2:$C$11;$D$2:$D$11;1));0); 0))/SUMPRODUCT(1/COUNTIF($C$2:$C$11;$C$2:$C$11))}
```

[image]

Comment: I am receiving an error when I copy and paste your formula? It looks like a syntax error?

Comment: Depending on the system localization, it may be necessary to replace the semicolon with a comma in the formulas

Comment: Yes, using commas worked. So this is calculating the retention of the customer correct? Is there a way to now calculate each employees total retention?

Comment: What do you mean by total retention? The existing formula in the 'Retention%' field is calculated by dividing the unique number of retained customers per employee by the total number of unique customers. Since only Tiffany is retained to the example, each employee to whom she appears is assigned 20% (i.e. 1/5). Can you add the desired calculation to your example?

Comment: My desired output would be maybe a separate table that shows each unique employees retention%. So maybe a sum for each employee over retention %?

Comment: We cannot sum existing percentages because they are already total. You have to figure out how to calculate it:
1. Unique customers retained / Total unique customers
2. Unique customers retained by each employee / Total unique customers - current calculation
3. Unique customers retained by each employee / Total unique customers per employee
4. Unique customers retained by each employee / Total unique retained customers 5. ...